# JQuery not working? Retrieve data from mysql database with no page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am working on a project and i am currently trying to implement a search function, after user type in what they want to search for in input box, they will click the "search" button and then the data will populate the existing table i have on my page. However, i do not want the page to refresh whenever a user click on search.

**Search button on my search.jsp**

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-labeled fa fa-search" type ="submit" name="action" value="search" id ="search" >Search</button>
```

**JavaScript / AJAX**

```
  $('#search').click(function () {
            alert("phase 1");
            $search = document.getElementById("search").value;
            alert("phase 2");
            $.post("editAction", { search: $search; }, function (data) {
                alert("phase 3");
                $('#dt-data').html(data);
            });
            alert("phase 4");
        });
```

**editAction.java** is where all the logic is and **dt-data** is the table i want to populate the data with

After running the codes, the alerts do not show & the page still refreshes but the table was still populated with the correct results. What am i doing wrong here? Any help appreciated, i am still new with js and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using a button with type of submit  `type ="submit"` this may submit your form directly on the same page. change this as following

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-labeled fa fa-search" type ="button" name="action" value="search" id ="search" >Search</button>
```

Edit 
chnage your function as following

```
$("#search").on("click",function(){
            $search = $("#search").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "editAction",
                type: "POST",
                data: { search: $search},
                success: function(data){
                    //do action  
                    alert("phase 3");
                    $('#dt-data').html(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    // do action
                    alert("phase 4");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your comment. After making changes like you have recommended, the button doesn't work anymore :( anymore tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-labeled fa fa-search" type ="submit" name="action" value="search" id ="search" >Search</button>
```

**JavaScript / AJAX:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#search").on("click",function(){
            $search = $("#search").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "editAction",
                type: "POST",
                data: { search: $search},
                success: function(data){
                    //do action  
                    alert("phase 3");
                    $('#dt-data').html(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    // do action
                    alert("phase 4");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your comment. I've tried your code and it alerted me "phase 4" :( means there's any error right?

Comment: After alerting, the page still refreshes and shows the right data in the table

Comment: You are using data table?

Comment: You can use `table.ajax.reload();   /// reloads the table` in success function ajax..

Comment: Assign data table to variable and then check  `var table = $('#example').DataTable({});`

Comment: i received an error message saying that i cannot reinitialise the table